# Traefik 2.2 with docker-compose configuration TLS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I've been trying to find a simple overview of how to enable SSL on a website with Traefik. All the examples are for the `.toml` file though, and I want to configure it using my `docker-compose` file.

The only sort of example I've found in the Traefik docs is this: https://docs.traefik.io/reference/dynamic-configuration/docker/

How can I convert the following config to a docker-compose setting?

```
[[tls.certificates]]
  certFile = "/path/to/domain.cert"
  keyFile = "/path/to/domain.key"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can't do this. Certificates definition is only supported through file provider. Quote from docs:

> In the above example, we've used the file provider to handle these
> definitions. It is the only available method to configure the
> certificates (as well as the options and the stores). However, in
> Kubernetes, the certificates can and must be provided by secrets.

See here: https://docs.traefik.io/https/tls/#user-defined

Comment: Thanks..i'm switching back to Traefik 1.7, too much trouble with 2.2 so far

Answer (score 0):

You should add labels to your yml file:

```
services:
  your-traefix-srv:
    build:
      labels:
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.middleware09.forwardauth.tls.cert=/path/to/domain.cert"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.middleware09.forwardauth.tls.key=/path/to/domain.key"
```

Additionally, add if you need:

```
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.middleware09.forwardauth.tls.ca=foobar"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.middleware09.forwardauth.tls.caoptional=true"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.middleware09.forwardauth.tls.insecureskipverify=true"
```

Finally, files `/path/to/domain.cert` and `/path/to/domain.key` should be added someway, well in Dockerfile and dockerbuilt time, well mounting them as bind volumes.

Comment: that might be true only if you want to forward certs to service, but that was not the question I believe